# Console based Hangman in Java

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, hangman

I just created a Hangman app (same game mechanics mostly) using Java. I did this mainly to test my knowledge in OOP design/coding. I'd like to know your thoughts on my code

The whole [project is on Github](https://github.com/zurcnay4/Hangman)

I would really appreciate the comments and criticism!

```
public class Launcher {
private static BufferedReader consoleReader;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("***LET'S PLAY HANGMAN (w/o the actual \"man\")***");
    System.out.print("Enter name:");
    String username = consoleReader.readLine();

    Player P1 = new Player(username);
    String plyrName = P1.getUsername();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + plyrName + "!");

    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 4) {
        try {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Start game");
            System.out.println("2. Help");
            System.out.println("3. About this game");
            System.out.println("4. Quit");

            choice = Integer.parseInt(consoleReader.readLine());
            if (choice == 1) {

                AI a1 = new AI(P1);
                String answer = a1.getAnswer();
                P1.setGuess(P1.initGuess(a1));

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("***Guess this " + answer.length() + " letter word!***");

                while (P1.getTries() != 0) {
                    try {
                        for (int x = 0; x < answer.length(); x++) {
                            System.out.print(P1.getGuess()[x] + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("1. Guess a letter");
                        System.out.println("2. Guess the answer");
                        System.out.println("3. Concede");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("No. of tries remaining: " + "*" + P1.getTries() + "*");
                        int controls = Integer.parseInt(consoleReader.readLine());

                        if (controls == 1) {
                            System.out.print("Input letter: ");
                            String ltr = consoleReader.readLine();

                            if (a1.isLetterInWord(P1, answer, ltr.toLowerCase())) {
                                if (String.valueOf(P1.getGuess()).equals(answer)) {
                                    System.out.println("***\"" + String.valueOf(P1.getGuess())  + "\"" + " is correct!***");
                                    System.out.print("***You have beaten the game, " + plyrName + "!***");
                                    P1.setTries(0);
                                }
                                System.out.println();
                            } else {
                                P1.setTries(P1.getTries() - 1);
                                if (P1.getTries() != 0) {
                                    System.out.println("***Sorry try again!***");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else if (controls == 2) {
                            System.out.print("Input guess: ");
                            String word = consoleReader.readLine();
                            if (a1.isGuessCorrect(answer, word.toLowerCase())) {
                                P1.setGuess(word.toCharArray());
                                System.out.println("***\"" + word + "\"" + " is correct!***");
                                System.out.println("***You have beaten the game, " + plyrName + "!***");
                                P1.setTries(0);

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("***Sorry try again!***");
                                P1.setTries(P1.getTries() - 1);
                            }
                        }

                        else if (controls == 3) {
                            System.out.println("***Are you sure you want to concede?***");
                            System.out.print("Y/N: ");
                            String yn = consoleReader.readLine();
                            while (!yn.toLowerCase().equals("n")) {
                                if(yn.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
                                    P1.setTries(0);
                                    break;
                                }
                                System.out.print("Y/N: ");
                                yn = consoleReader.readLine();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("***ERROR: Invalid input!***");
                    }
                }

                if (P1.getTries() == 0 && !String.valueOf(P1.getGuess()).equals(answer)) {
                    System.out.println("***GAME OVER, " + plyrName + "!***");
                    System.out.println("***The answer is " + "\"" + answer + "\"***");
                }
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("              ***Help***");
                System.out.println("You will be given a word to try and guess.");
                System.out.println("Your number of trials will depend on the length of the word.");
                System.out.println("You can guess it by letter or guess it directly.");
                System.out.println("Goodluck; Have fun!");
                System.out.println("              ***Help***");
            }
            else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("          ***About this game***");
                System.out.println("This game was developed to check and exercise");
                System.out.println("zurcnay4's OOP knowledge using java. \n");
                System.out.println("Comments & suggestions on: ");
                System.out.println("- the application's overall design/code");
                System.out.println("- how to improve this game");
                System.out.println("are highly appreciated! \n");
                System.out.println("Fork on github: https://github.com/zurcnay4/Hangman");
                System.out.println("          ***About this game***");
            }
            else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("***Are you sure you want to quit?***");
                System.out.print("Y/N: ");
                String yn = consoleReader.readLine();
                while (!yn.toLowerCase().equals("n")) {
                    if ((yn.toLowerCase().equals("y"))) {
                        choice = 4;
                        System.out.println("***Goodbye, " + plyrName + "***");
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print("Y/N: ");
                    yn = consoleReader.readLine();
                }
                if ((yn.toLowerCase().equals("n"))) {
                    choice = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("***ERROR: Invalid input!***");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Couple of concerns

- Is there a need to use an abstract class/Interface in my project?
- Did I do abstraction correctly? Did I create the right classes/objects?
- Is my code readable?
- Am I following the right conventions?

Please do check the GitHub repo to see the whole application. Aside from the main class, I have these classes:

- `AI`
- `AIService`
- `Player`
- `PlayerService`
- `Dictionary`

Answer (score 5):

Please split your code into different smaller functions.
This is just impossible to understand. Here's my attempt, it probably doesn't compile but it does look much easier to understand :

```
public class Launcher {
    private static BufferedReader consoleReader;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("***LET'S PLAY HANGMAN (w/o the actual \"man\")***");
        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        String username = consoleReader.readLine();

        Player P1 = new Player(username);
        String plyrName = P1.getUsername();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + plyrName + "!");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Start game");
            System.out.println("2. Help");
            System.out.println("3. About this game");
            System.out.println("4. Quit");

            switch (askUserInteger(0)) {
                case 1: game(P1); break;
                case 2: help(); break;
                case 3: about(); break;
                case 4:
                    if (userWantsToQuit()) {
                        System.out.println("***Goodbye, " + plyrName + "***");
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("***ERROR: Invalid input!***");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void game (Player P1)
    {
        AI a1 = new AI(P1);
        String answer = a1.getAnswer();
        P1.setGuess(P1.initGuess(a1));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("***Guess this " + answer.length() + " letter word!***");

        while (P1.getTries() != 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < answer.length(); x++) {
                System.out.print(P1.getGuess()[x] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Guess a letter");
            System.out.println("2. Guess the answer");
            System.out.println("3. Concede");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No. of tries remaining: " + "*" + P1.getTries() + "*");

            switch (askUserInteger(0)) {
                case 1: guessLetter(P1); break;
                case 2: guessAnswer(P1); break;
                case 3 : if (userWantsToConcede()) P1.setTries(0); break;
                default : System.out.println("***ERROR: Invalid input!***");
            }
        }

        if (P1.getTries() == 0 && !String.valueOf(P1.getGuess()).equals(answer)) {
            System.out.println("***GAME OVER, " + plyrName + "!***");
            System.out.println("***The answer is " + "\"" + answer + "\"***");
        }
    }

    public static void guessLetter(Player P1)
    {
        System.out.print("Input letter: ");
        String ltr = consoleReader.readLine();

        if (a1.isLetterInWord(P1, answer, ltr.toLowerCase())) {
            if (String.valueOf(P1.getGuess()).equals(answer)) {
                System.out.println("***\"" + String.valueOf(P1.getGuess())  + "\"" + " is correct!***");
                System.out.print("***You have beaten the game, " + plyrName + "!***");
                P1.setTries(0);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            P1.setTries(P1.getTries() - 1);
            if (P1.getTries() != 0) {
                System.out.println("***Sorry try again!***");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void guessAnswer(Player P1)
    {
        System.out.print("Input guess: ");
        String word = consoleReader.readLine();
        if (a1.isGuessCorrect(answer, word.toLowerCase())) {
            P1.setGuess(word.toCharArray());
            System.out.println("***\"" + word + "\"" + " is correct!***");
            System.out.println("***You have beaten the game, " + plyrName + "!***");
            P1.setTries(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("***Sorry try again!***");
            P1.setTries(P1.getTries() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void help ()
    {
        System.out.println("              ***Help***");
        System.out.println("You will be given a word to try and guess.");
        System.out.println("Your number of trials will depend on the length of the word.");
        System.out.println("You can guess it by letter or guess it directly.");
        System.out.println("Goodluck; Have fun!");
        System.out.println("              ***Help***");
    }

    public static void about()
    {
        System.out.println("          ***About this game***");
        System.out.println("This game was developed to check and exercise");
        System.out.println("zurcnay4's OOP knowledge using java. \n");
        System.out.println("Comments & suggestions on: ");
        System.out.println("- the application's overall design/code");
        System.out.println("- how to improve this game");
        System.out.println("are highly appreciated! \n");
        System.out.println("Fork on github: https://github.com/zurcnay4/Hangman");
        System.out.println("          ***About this game***");
    }
    public static bool userWantsToConcede()
    {
        return askUserYesNoQuestion("***Are you sure you want to concede?***");
    }
    public static bool userWantsToQuit()
    {
        return askUserYesNoQuestion("***Are you sure you want to quit?***");
    }
    public static bool askUserYesNoQuestion(String question)
    {
        System.out.println(question);
        do {
            System.out.print("Y/N: ");
            String yn = consoleReader.readLine();
            if (yn.toLowerCase().equals("y")) return true;
        }
        while (!yn.toLowerCase().equals("n"));
        return false;
    }
    public static int askUserInteger(int defValue)
    {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(consoleReader.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return defValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! it makes it more readable indeed!

Comment: Question: with the functions game() about() help()... would it be better if I separate them in other classes to make it more OOP?

Answer (score 4):

Nitpick: the variable `P1` should be named `p1`, since the convention is to use uppercase for class names and constants.

I agree with @Josay that this function desperately needs to be broken up!

Since you indicate that you want to exercise OOP, I suggest creating a `Menu` class to help reduce the tedium of prompting for user choices.

```
public class Menu {
    public final String[] choices;

    public Menu(String... choices) {
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    int promptInt(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= this.choices.length; i++) {
                out.printf("%d. %s\n", i, this.choices[i - 1]);
            }
            out.flush();
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            if (choice > 0 && choice <= this.choices.length) {
                return choice;
            }
        }
    }

    boolean promptYN(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        assert 1 == this.choices.length;
        out.println(this.choices[0]);
        while (true) {
            out.print("Y/N: ");
            out.flush();
            switch (Character.toLowerCase(in.readLine().charAt(0))) {
              case 'y': return true;
              case 'n': return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
static Menu mainMenu = new Menu(
    /* 1 */ "Start game",
    /* 2 */ "Help",
    /* 3 */ "About",
    /* 4 */ "Quit"
);
static Menu quitMenu = new Menu("***Are you sure you want to quit?***");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader conIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter conOut = new PrintWriter(System.out);

    while (true) {
        switch (mainMenu.promptInt(conIn, conOut)) {
          case 1: game(conIn, conOut); break;
          case 2: help(conIn, conOut); break;
          case 3: about(conIn, conOut); break;
          case 4:
            if (quitMenu.promptYN(conIn, conOut)) {
                System.out.println("Bye!"); return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I didn't think of making a Menu class thank you for pointing that out! Did you check the project on github? what are your thoughts on the classes that I created?